# Which approach of mine for an algorithm upper bound is correct?

Tags: asymptotics, big-o-notation, python

Say we have this algorithm in Python.

```python
def secret(S: list):
   n = len(S)
   while n > 0:
      n = n // 2
      for j in range(n):
         if j in S:
            S.append(j)
   return S
```

I need to find the strictest upper bound (Big-$O$).
I have two approaches to solve this, which give me different solutions and I would appreciate your help deciding which one is correct!

**The first approach:**

According to the python documentations, the `x in s` operator is $O(n)$ where $n$ is the length of the list.
(Provided here: https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity)

So, at the worst case, in each of the for loop, we search the element $|S|$ times. Say that $|S| = N$, then in each iteration the length of $S$ at the worst case gets bigger by $1$ - because it does contain $j$ each time, and it adds this $j$.

The first iteration of the `while loop`: $\text{range}(N/2)$

$$ N + (N+1) + (N+2) + \dots + N + \frac{N}{2} = \frac{N^2}{2} + 1 + 2 + \dots + \frac{N}{2} = \frac{N^2}{2} + \frac{\frac{N}{2}(\frac{N}{2} + 1)}{2}$$

At the second iteration of the `while loop`: $\text{range}(N/4)$

$$N + \frac{N}{2} + (N + \frac{N}{2} + 1) + (N + \frac{N}{2} + 2)  + \dots + (N + \frac{N}{2} + \frac{N}{4}) = \frac{N^2}{4} + \frac{N^2}{8} + 1 + 2 + 3 + \dots + \frac{N}{4} = \frac{N^2}{4} + \frac{N^2}{8} + \frac{\frac{N}{4}(\frac{N}{4} + 1)}{2}$$

The $k$-th iteration is by:

$$I_k = \frac{N^2}{2^k} + \frac{N}{2^{k-1}} \cdot \frac{N}{2^k} + \sum_{i=1}^{N/2^k} i$$

and over and over... exactly $\lg(N)$ times.

$$ \sum_{k=1}^{\lg(N)} I_k$$

Which is (if I am not wrong here): $$O(N^2 \lg (N))$$

**The second approach:**

The second approach is like the first, but I noticed that while it's true that the `x in S` operator is $O(|S|)$, it is not $|S|$ (the **current** size) in this case specifically, as we insert these numbers if they are already in the array! so each iteration will be at most $O(N)$ and not $O(|S|)$

And so the math gets easier and we do on the first iteration:

$$\overset{N/2 \text{ times}}{N + N + N + \dots + N} = N^2 / 2$$

On the second iteration it would be:

$$\overset{N/4 \text{ times}}{N + N + N + \dots + N} = N^2 / 4$$

and this keeps going of course, $\lg(N)$ times, so we have this sum:

$$ \sum_{k=1}^{\lg(N)} N^2 / 2^k$$

Which at the end goes to be:

$$O(N^2)$$

---

Which one is correct?

When we recognize the 'live' updating size of $N$ (starting at $N$, then $N+1$, then all the way to $N+N/2$, then $N+N/2+1$ all the way to $N+N/2+N/4$, ...)

Or not recognize the live updating size, as the `in` operator would surely find the number **at most** $N$ iterations? ($N$ is the starting size of $S$.)

Comment: You can improve the bound in your first approach. Use the fact that geometric series converge.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus But all along the first approach is wrong no? Because it is not correct that in the second iteration overall takes $O(N+1)$ because the number $j$ would be found in $O(N)$ each iteration

Comment: And so the second iteration overall and third, they are not going to take $O(N+2)$ and $O(N+2)$ because they would be found beforehand, in the first $N$ elements, so it would be $O(N)$, so which approach is correct?

Comment: I didn’t read it deeply enough.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Would appreciate your kind help! :)

Comment: @fastttt In your first approach, it is not wrong technically that $\sum_{k=1}^{\lg(N)} I_k = O(N^2 \lg (N))$. However, the left-hand side is, in fact,  $O(N^2)$.

Comment: @fastttt Your second approach seems faulty since `if x in S` does take $|S|$ time when $x$ is not in $S$.

Comment: @JohnL. But here specifically, the number we search will be in the list no matter what, in the first $N$ elements, if it is not there, the `in` operator would take as you said $N$ (or $|S|$) , and wont be added to the list, and if it is there already, adding it wont add to the complexity of the `in` operator because it would find it in the first N elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### A simple proof of $\Theta(N^2)$ time-complexity

Each iteration of the `while loop` will cut $n$ in half and, at worst, increases the size of $S$ by $n$. In the $i$-th iteration of the `while loop`, $n\le\frac{N}{2^i}$.

Hence the line `S.append(j)` can be executed at most $N/2 + N/4 + N/8+\cdots = N$
times. So, $|S|$ is at most $N + N= 2N$ at any time.

Each appendment takes $O(1)$ time except possibly when the capacity of $S$ is doubled, at which time the appendment takes $O(N)$ time, assuming the usual implementation of Python.  So, the total time that is spent on that line is at most $O(N)$.

Now consider the total time spent on `if j in S`. Each execution will take at most $|S|$ time. So the total time is no more than
$$ \frac{N}2 (2N) + \frac{N}{2^2}(2N) + \frac{N}{2^3}(2N) + \cdots = 2N^2$$

Hence, $O(N^2)$ is an upper bound.

---

Consider the first iteration of the while loop, which is basically

```python
      for j in range(N//2):
         if j in S:
           #
```

If `j` is not in $S$, `if j in S` will take $\Theta(|S|)$ time. In order to execute `if j in S` faster, we can assume all `j`s are in $S$. Since it takes different number of lookups to find different `j`s, the least total number of lookups needed to execute `if j in S` `for j in range(N//2)` is
$$1 + 2 + \cdots + (N//2-1)=\Theta(N^2).$$

Hence, $\Omega(N^2)$ is a lower bound.

---

So, the time-complexity is $\Theta(N^2)$.

In particular, the strictest upper bound in big $O$-notation is $O(N^2)$.

##### "You can improve the bound in your first approach"

Let us do the math more carefully.

> The $k$-th iteration is by:
> $$I_k = \frac{N^2}{2^k} + \frac{N}{2^{k-1}} \cdot \frac{N}{2^k} + \sum_{i=1}^{N/2^k} i$$

So, $$I_k = \frac{N^2}{2^k} + \frac{N^2}{2^{k}}\frac1{2^{k-1}} + \frac N{2^k}(\frac N{2^k}+1)/2= \frac{N^2}{2^k}(1 + \frac1{2^{k-1}}+\frac1{2^k}+\frac1N)\lt\frac{N^2}{2^k}(1+1+1+1)=\frac{4N^2}{2^k}$$

So, $$ \sum_{k=1}^{\lg(N)} I_k\le 4N^2\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac1{2^k}=4N^2.$$

Comment: In the first approach, i took the fact that if we find the number in the list, we add it, and thus if in the first iteration the `in` operator took $O(N)$ the second one would take $O(N+1)$ and so on.. and the maths get $O(N^2 \lg(N))$. The second approach says this: if we find the number, it is already in the first $N$ elements, and if it is not there, we wont add it and it would take $O(N)$.  thus we can say in this situation the `in` operator takes $O(N)$ (starting value of $|S|$) and not the "updating" size of $S$. So which approach is more correct in your opinion?

Comment: @fastttt, please come [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135245/chat-with-john-l) for a chat.

Comment: Thank you so much! :)

Comment: @fastttt You are welcome!